# Apache 2.x Mime Magic Module

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I am getting this error when complinng Apache with mod-mime-magic:

> --enable-mime-magic ../build_apache.sh: line 22:
>
> --enable-mime-magic: command not found

When I look at the output on screen, I see the following:

> checking whether to enable mod_mime_magic... no

despite the fact that --enable-mime-magic is passed in the build script. Also, a little later, I see this:

> checking whether to enable mod_mime... yes (default)

I googled this error, but not much comes up. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Here is the build script:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/lib

export PATH

set -e
set -x

make distclean || true

./configure --prefix=/app/apache \
        --enable-so \
        --enable-cgi \
        --enable-info \
        --enable-rewrite \
        --enable-speling \
        --enable-usertrack \
        --enable-deflate \
#       --enable-ssl \
#       --with-ssl=/usr/bin \
        --enable-mime-magic
#make
#make install
#/app/apache/bin/apachectl restart
```

This is on Apache 2.2.17 and Redhat (RHEL) 5.5.

Thanks!

KM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the commented lines from your ./configure list. They are causing --enable-mime-magic to be processed as a separate command.